# How to decode a Base64 data string to print text in Python to achieve image to text

Tags: python, image, selenium, text, tesseract

I have been working at this for a while now but cannot seem to figure it out.

I am using Selenium to automate entering giftcards into a giftcard checking website.

However, the results are in an encrypted format (data:image/jpg;charset=UTF-8;base64,)

I then remove the prefix using:
new_data = imgs.replace('data:image/jpg;charset=UTF-8;base64,', '')

Which then leaves me with the base64 data I believe.

However, `base64.b64decode(new_data)` throws the error:

```
line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Can anyone give me the best way to either fix this or to continue on and successfully achieve image to text with this data?

For reference, the base64 data here:

```
%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD%2F2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL%2F2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL%2FwAARCABGAaQDASIAAhEBAxEB%2F8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4%2BTl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3%2BPn6%2F8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3%2BPn6%2F9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDoPCvhXw9ceEdGmm0Oyl8y1tGmnbTI2kEhjgIVQYTvRtzF5CSVJbkYOzEfUvDX2%2B6tI%2Fhre3XkXBjuZtP0W3njiljKBoo22DfG2HyzYcbuAMjZ2PhAZ8I%2BH5szfu7C0j88QZki3R258qMeUd0T4y75O0g8jb%2B74fw3a%2BM4G1pvD0Hhy0gg1qWACWGaSSEl4t0UZRMeSdqAnaMAE%2FLtBVdbf10Hb3b%2Bf%2BZ02haNoGt6Yt7P4Ij0oPOiyw3WkRCWJ8xDZGvknfC2XzI2CMsflH3NJfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHy8XXR4h03wQ7ztYWmqW08VtHNp8bxR2qtJbhYoQUBaJlGW%2BYjI28gYTNl8OT6brXh7QY9d1yAPDcRXM0cjPJCCtt%2B6t3EagRBgnzBcKA2cYO1%2FwBfhcR1i%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl8npvhu%2F13ULpLjW9U0y00QrpFpFpVwd8B2QAgsI90qM2CWO3bsBIx9yul7rGoeHvC8S3rWd0NXfSZryyiEflxquwpAFjAMTCMMT0VlHGFAQ00t1t%2BIf8H8DtF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLm0fR%2FwCwNFtrJZbx%2FsSLB9okzNNBuMJ8mJvJG%2BE%2FxPxtx%2FDt%2Fd%2Ba2rapo3gLTPEFtqGqzX08UWmJ5alxaRs8RC28LJtcsiAFt33gAOfunW39ah0PRF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLrWXh%2FwpqCzNFoWkEQ3SwXfkadG%2F2edTEDCmYBvjJLbpDyuScgfc5DwZNqNhr2j2cGneNILGSD7PcPq1n5oszlCqQybPliYpsbhRja3ykArm6No954e8Ka9c6dd3EF3b6r%2FZ6ObkuLcieAYQbF3K3R2%2BXIRRt%2Fuu2tv63sHS%2Fn%2BjZ38nh7w9FqdvZTeELUfaGDTT2%2BkxyRW0i%2BTiJWMA3RvubMh5Hz8rg7La%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5fLm0k8GatosCX%2BrzvbWl00iuWm2kLbN5MX7sAwcAZCgKNxypX5eV03VdbiOl65Yad41m1BYAQq2A%2Fs8RkxnyYogDtiZFxuBBGxTg5%2BVLV2%2Frd%2F5A9D1JfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHy61x4b8P281rHL4RtG%2B0XUcUzWulxyLavtjbaCYRugPzBpTyCxHH%2FLOlPqSeF%2FFTy6g0tpYS2CeSsUZdLKSLyjLBBmPHkumzcygAbGPylflz7WPUNNsvBzyy3cM0%2BrKswAYG3jljDi1iGzBgwEzg4Up%2Fs%2FIf8AA%2FO3%2BYf8H8rnTL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXwEek6tcaDrWvvrmp2LaNNeQWVvYSN5dttZMRAeXmSElRk5VVCDjAO3cLTeIr%2FQdLW%2FvtJg%2FstLiRtNg8qRN4gUQwOseRCGKsxGQOhIC4VLVL%2Bul%2FwBBtWevn%2BDt%2Bp0a%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5dSTw94ei1O3spvCFqPtDBpp7fSY5IraRfJxErGAbo33NmQ8j5%2BVwdmd4Fsr%2FAEnWtY0u9vZriPTDaW0EykzSWyMIiIEHl4MZAAdwE4QMQOqXNReS08aeH4EkuLMR2s8RgtIcxw8W37qP92N0WQMvjjLcpt%2BRt2%2FryuJa%2FwBeZoL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FAHsYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl4mp23hfTNZs9Jk8GxXN7dsskqWGkxSi12%2BTkKWhUPCdzBpOoJIGD9zlLGw1XTvAuleME1%2FUzc6dHHCkJYrAkTSRAQrHs%2FeKVI3PuwCijBI%2BXoDo0Y%2BL9i%2FwBt1Wy8jTY3NpZO%2FkRkPEohjHljdb%2FMNxAA4JJXaQHZ8yXm%2FwAFcL6P%2Butjpl8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfL43TtK1HxDpsniga7qGlT2bzWtpBY7ltrNUkRY4hH5eJYjtBd8hQFAI%2BU7ZjNP4huvB6w32oaTFeWEiSrYQmNoFKW2I4CqcR7tpLfMF%2BYEgLhUtf69f8gejOsXwh4eOfO8N6ZH%2B9jE3labG%2FlSHysRx5g%2FeRHLbpDyuW5XB8sXwh4eOfO8N6ZH%2B9jE3labG%2FlSHysRx5g%2FeRHLbpDyuW5XB8vjLPw9qV7qOsWT61qenWeirDa2v9n3LvLC7QwgJu8vc0OQC2Ng%2BXcw7pHZxasNL8KeLk1i7SdZLazktkTyrVIZWiHlRxbMFSpBZw2AyAAZHyC1%2FD8dhf8H8Dt18IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLrXPh%2FwpZNAuoaFpFqbm6igO3To22TkRkQxZg%2FeRsN%2BZDgjJGQfucd4jGo3%2FAIimh0yHxJLJp0K2sUOhSrZ2liT5IaATFMuM%2FMThcBV%2BXaCUoS2k3iPwl4Dvbm9vYZE1FbDzLfEBtw21VEQWPDDEYO8EhWyOeiC1Sfp%2BJXf5%2Fgeg2%2FhnQJrm4huPCNlbCKWESyLpkTqHPlfJD%2B5%2FeRElw0jYK5PQcpYXwh4eOfO8N6ZH%2B9jE3labG%2FlSHysRx5g%2FeRHLbpDyuW5XB8vk7y81fTpdVsrGWGymS8sdLt7gP5v9nrKkAZIVZAChwc%2Fd5VTjP3bFnpF14J8ReHLeDV9TuLe6cadPBdN9oa3IRJALdmiH7k7QrlQBgDoVygrP%2BvJP9RPQ6RfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHyxfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHy%2BAj0nVrjQda199c1OxbRpryCyt7CRvLttrJiIDy8yQkqMnKqoQcYB299pNr%2FaFr4f1bzbu1%2BzQRr5dpEFSPzEt%2F3KIIvngOMls%2FIQeRt%2Fdi1V%2FT8Qejt6%2FgKvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP8AexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FAHsYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgGSvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5YvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5YvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP8AexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgGSvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5YvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FAHsYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgHzF8ULOKw%2BImp20Nla2SIsBNvagCKNjBGWC4VcjJPOBnrgUVJ8VovI%2BI%2BpQ%2FZ4bby4rZfIgOY48W8Y2qcD5R0HA4HQUUAfQfhAZ8I%2BH5szfu7C0j88QZki3R258qMeUd0T4y75O0g8jb%2B7xF%2BGdjFqD3dvqviHStzss0OmXbJHBLKYjshUQjdFyMvwB5YyPlO3b8IDPhHw%2FNmb93YWkfniDMkW6O3PlRjyjuifGXfJ2kHkbf3etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sC%2Bljn7DwTZ2mgR6Rdz6ncRQvErTTStPLbPugZYYG8kZgyq7mAAGznGDs0%2F7GQ6rp1%2B32i1bTlFusNqmY4C4gHlRr5PzwkA5k425bpj93dgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sA5a%2B%2BHemXurHUkm1TR52iS0uho8rRKuVhVYkAhHmRdy%2FAGOeBhNOPwrp8UejRi3mtY9HuEeJbdS5gkZYx5SM0O6SFizM8hIII5IwdmtBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2Fdi02DcSK2EaRKYPswhCW%2F8Ao8O77LnyP3EH7kboGx8z8bcdtv7vGTwhp7%2BGIdAvobiS1gWOBpNu%2BWBi0DeXE4hXfEzDLScYx2x%2B72oIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sA53w94ItdAubW5e81i5ms0jt0e5uHuBZsTF%2B7gUwhWiZTtaQAbQvG0hirY%2FAOkxzXTeXd20NxJF51vbktFazb4XC26%2BTzGxC73GANgyBtOzpIIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7svrcCi2ixvqen3zie2%2Fs9Pswgto8xQ7xAPJjXyfnhIBy%2FG3LdMfu%2BeHwy0k31tNLPrMVnbOqvpsd1JLbROzxP5UaNFl4S2CzZAGznGDs6%2BCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuxaAZOseFdM1%2B0s7TVbJkgspowqWyH%2FRmKxKIIcRDfAwJ3NxjHOAMJYudCt7y40ma4hktzpNxG0S2sWRbOUiUQRfuRvgOSWfjaV7BcJegg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sAx7XwpZWuiXelLHPbQ3LSRzvBGGe1M5iLQwHyAGgOcF8fLt5xtOzB8T6WLKx0i2fSPEk66fGsEd7oMn%2BkWTCKMGKP92nmRMBkv%2FeyOPujtoIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7Vh3OE%2BF3h%2BTSIL2%2BbSb3SoppYYo1uUMl3HgQ5XmLmORidzDaFC9sZTrW0SOTUtPvXNxaHT0%2BzCG0TMcG8QDyox5HzxEA5k425bpj93egg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2Fu29f6%2BRKVjEHhCyfwtF4fuxdfZoVjt2mRd81uxaBhHE3kjfEWGWfHGOcY%2BS5BoccGvQasDc20lvbR2BhtkzFbgtAwiiXyBviPIMmRtBb7uP3d%2BCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuzrcfkchN8MdFn1N7lm1SwtZGCXmnafO62wkfyd0aIIgXibA3uCoGwdMHZ0K6JGupaZek3NqdNQWyw2y7o4N4gHlRgw5kiIBzJkbct0x%2B7vQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZ2n%2BHbPTbq7uYbZ7SW5aKO4NvHv%2BzttgUQwfueYWUAM%2FAXb2IJSCDwrZpo2maZdLctFprwKsoG%2BSF1MDLHGwhHmQsw3O%2FGCvOACE2IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7s%2F4H4bB%2FX3nJ3Pw20q61d755dWsIZAsF3Y6dO6W4ZlhUxoqwgvCwA3uCANnOMHZYXwFpv8AwjlposzahFHYzhorqBybiyldo2CQSCEF4sscyHpt5%2B6dnSQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392dLAYLeB9Hms7u1u7JxHdCCC6MaFjAyiALHAfJGYiFXc4xt2%2Fw4OyLw94HtNAu7W6a71e5uLRI7ZXubh7j7ISY%2FwB3AphCtEwYq0gA2heNp3Fejgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuzrcOljHtfClla6Jd6Usc9tDctJHO8EYZ7UzmItDAfIAaA5wXx8u3nG07J7XQvsr6O32i%2Bg%2FslFtsQ%2FMF3LAvkj9wPNhOMs%2FG0gnjH7vRgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sB6hBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgHzN8VovI%2BI%2BpQ%2FZ4bby4rZfIgOY48W8Y2qcD5R0HA4HQUUfFaLyPiPqUP2eG28uK2XyIDmOPFvGNqnA%2BUdBwOB0FFAH0H4QGfCPh%2BbM37uwtI%2FPEGZIt0dufKjHlHdE%2BMu%2BTtIPI2%2Fu9aCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O393k%2BEBnwj4fmzN%2B7sLSPzxBmSLdHbnyox5R3RPjLvk7SDyNv7vWgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YB8zfFaLyPiPqUP2eG28uK2XyIDmOPFvGNqnA%2BUdBwOB0FFHxWi8j4j6lD9nhtvLitl8iA5jjxbxjapwPlHQcDgdBRQB9B%2BEBnwj4fmzN%2B7sLSPzxBmSLdHbnyox5R3RPjLvk7SDyNv7vya1t%2FhvHqusW3i2OGzvU1ObK2z3BEKK6bYkCR7DGcSAk7WAxgDIK%2Bs%2BEBnwj4fmzN%2B7sLSPzxBmSLdHbnyox5R3RPjLvk7SDyNv7vkdI%2F4S7wtLqkNp4CMy%2F2ozQz2t5CgjjkaI%2BVGGjJMR2oCwAwAc7Cnyrr8v8AIr7PzX5MvaTqXh7w34GOveGrRn09bhfMMTOXid3gWSKEzRbnjbaSxOCSMDBxsc%2Fi%2FV9OextH8F3Nvqk0jQWNlbzREwxoLc%2BWj%2BVtWFh945O3aRkEDY%2B%2Bg1zW%2FDM0M%2FhT%2BzJ7a8t7eC3EqSmGISWx2xFIwPKIBLHcdpT0GE159Lux4q0O7jimt7Swja3mW2iBjtmcW4WKL92C8RwQXC%2FKC3Kbflr1%2FrQj%2BvxMu78U6pbTm30Lwhc302nCGG4%2BzSwolgWEWbWE%2BWd6fKN5A4znKgLtcfGUMehaJqel6RLIbqdbGO3jVYpLN9iE20W6IBoi0W1myMHoRtASo1r4m8J6hfvonheC%2FhuLiJkNrIsTWTssIeFS8f7yA7YxuQAAKclSuVW18H3%2BlWnhmEQrNLYaybi9mt4dotvNAJjhUxjdCSy7mBO3HbadiWqXy%2F4PyG9L%2FP8ALQ6TR59QeSAXmgS6UsKJGGhMcv2Ml4gLaMLF80TKqszjIX5huGz5OZ%2BI%2BijU9L0HTDbpb7tShtAYkwLMtCuIoD5S74sgEt2K47YTsIPPg1CKA6a1tb28UUYubZFZbZiYQbWFfKBaEgAtJjAweV2%2FJka%2FpF1cT%2BG3ttPULpuqW5mEMfFkmyMGOD90u%2BHJBZh0x2Cny1vb1%2FUadr%2Bj%2FIypdSk1H4e2a2am3vrsJpCssSo9pIxiSSKEeXgxYR2Yg8FcA8fJj%2BDha2vhPwelzZy3Eia1Lbw3GSr2j7ycR%2Fuv3kbBTuJPBJ5BUbN3S%2FC93a%2BMfNlsUs9I0%2BXzrQ2kW%2Fy7icQh4owY%2BYRhwXCgAOfulDsoaP4X1ex0jwtDPp7pNpmtPJcFVVmtY3bISLCfPE25SzAnac5xtPl0nfXu1%2FX5iaSVu1%2Fyf%2FALGjeNb3ULpnsPCVydLsbpbE3ljLDI9oB5QeKKHyw5hJVcnrtJPylQFs6v4qvNK1yPRNF8Ntf6naQwGSK3nhhFnG5iHkwbotzxEoNzBRtBzlcDZyl94N1mfUrgJ4LtrDUkuoo4db0q7aGC1zs2mOBUDOozhnIPJf5lC%2FLr%2BMfDd9evDHN4LttbtYfs0UYspvsklmwCBoVfYPNgO77wHy7pMlNo2r7KD7TNi5vbS4j8JXNxodzau1%2FDDDE8Zhk0xzGh8qNfKHmREKQx6DPBG0bM1vHOp2tnd3ln4LuWtdHuGtZ57WeHZaRI0YeOAGIM8ZEYLfKMeq4BWa18MaxZaf4TgnWS5k0rVFM0oG57OFgAsMZKZkiwyBnBOCp7L8j7Hw7qNt4J1%2FTm00Wt3LNeRQLboGMQmaMpFEfLwYX43Pxtxzt2nyx3V%2Fn%2Bn%2FBGknb5fr%2FwCzqXimXTho8GiaBNqGo3MKNDbWoWMWcOLcmNHaHHkNkBn7EY%2BXb%2B7s%2BFtdm1a9vbabQ5dGbSpIbbYNkklvu8r9zGqRY8htnLZ4GGBAwUw7i21rw%2Fd6Dd6XCt5qttYQ2F1pJlSKUJ%2B4OICUIaINkO%2FIG5vmXb8k%2FgQXr%2BJfEVzfadb6dJHPbW4WxAla1XEQW3XCEFdoUSEEBdoIwPmVq138%2Fzt%2BRF3ZX8vyIfGWg6drXijwhpGq28q2YeVHtbaNhHCRHARFEyxqWiz1fHGW5XbhIp%2FB9r4H1fS9c8PRy6cxvobTUoBO8iMsphBijMifOmcnfkHOR14TR8VWevWmreHNT0TRZbw6XI0MtnbOkSW%2B9IFEUTNGN0XXLhTj5uU2%2FJHb6fr%2FiPVLH%2B2NBXQNJ0i8hKQIVuJHx5WyKIxxgLBuCM55wR1AT5FHpb5%2Ff%2FAJFPb5E%2FiLxLqfhlfMtfCrtb2PkQvdfaYLaC1D%2BUDBAzxgvCSqhmwMc8rtG3G1nxVeXOheEtX8N6TPsnv4oREkiQCEbU%2FwBDjbYN0LlMluVymDjAC19S8L6tDr2oSr4Is9Skllggt7x591vZIViAhELx%2FPEp4LoowpbBQg7Zk8M%2BIdO8EaBGukG71TQ9VWRoNyq2DIuI4X2YMTBg7MWO0gg%2Fdwijsm%2B6%2FwCD939XG92vX8tP6%2FI2tf8AE%2BqeG4lltvCchgshBE9y1zBbQ2gfygbeFnj%2BeElVDNgY55XaNu34Z1S113Q9P1eytpLW3ZUiRUgBa05hBgixFhoSVO588Y6jH7vgr%2Fwzq8et3048C2uoTTSW8NvdSzh4LBCsQEIhZCHiQ8F0UYUtgqQdvX%2BBNIv9E8L2VlqUMkN3ZytA8iRh3i3SxkJFiM7oZBgu2fl55G3924%2FDd%2F1%2FX9XE99P6%2Fr%2BrHQQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgHzN8VovI%2BI%2BpQ%2FZ4bby4rZfIgOY48W8Y2qcD5R0HA4HQUUfFaLyPiPqUP2eG28uK2XyIDmOPFvGNqnA%2BUdBwOB0FFAHUaP8bRpWkafZnQXlmsoIreO4%2B1xhlRFjDIuYSQjmIFgSTzwRhcW0%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAGRrnxR0DxHZQ2epeChJBbyI1ssd%2Bsf2dFCgxIVhBCELyDn7xwRhdtrSPjFpeg2q22leD%2FskaPuiKXyFo1JQugZoSxV%2FLG4sS3PBGF2lFC0Dcup8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQB5n4r1yLxJ4judUt9PTT4ZViSO1jYMsSpGqAAgAYwvTAx0ooooA%2F%2FZ
```

The result should show:

"Error retrieving information:"
and
"Error: Missing Data"

I'm new to coding and am planning on using something like tesseract to decode but I have no idea how to!

UPDATE: I got a bit further, and have successfully parsed the data:image/jpg string above, but have no idea how to pull the text from the image! Please help! Assume I should use tesseract!

Comment: Please show the entirety of your code rather than a description of what you're doing and a couple snippets.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to use OCR module like `pytesseract` to get text from image. And this may need first write it in file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of encodings applied to the data that you have provided. First it is url encoded and second it is base64 encoded. You need to decode them in sequence first using `urllib.parse.unquote` to remove the url encoding. Then use `base64.b64decode` to remove the base64 encoding. Once these two encodings are removed, you can then see the JPEG magic number `JFIF` in the resulting data. You now have JPEG data that you can use for the next steps of your mission.

Here is a code snippet:

```py
import base64
import urllib.parse

data = '%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD%2F2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL%2F2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL%2FwAARCABGAaQDASIAAhEBAxEB%2F8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4%2BTl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3%2BPn6%2F8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3%2BPn6%2F9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDoPCvhXw9ceEdGmm0Oyl8y1tGmnbTI2kEhjgIVQYTvRtzF5CSVJbkYOzEfUvDX2%2B6tI%2Fhre3XkXBjuZtP0W3njiljKBoo22DfG2HyzYcbuAMjZ2PhAZ8I%2BH5szfu7C0j88QZki3R258qMeUd0T4y75O0g8jb%2B74fw3a%2BM4G1pvD0Hhy0gg1qWACWGaSSEl4t0UZRMeSdqAnaMAE%2FLtBVdbf10Hb3b%2Bf%2BZ02haNoGt6Yt7P4Ij0oPOiyw3WkRCWJ8xDZGvknfC2XzI2CMsflH3NJfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHy8XXR4h03wQ7ztYWmqW08VtHNp8bxR2qtJbhYoQUBaJlGW%2BYjI28gYTNl8OT6brXh7QY9d1yAPDcRXM0cjPJCCtt%2B6t3EagRBgnzBcKA2cYO1%2FwBfhcR1i%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl8npvhu%2F13ULpLjW9U0y00QrpFpFpVwd8B2QAgsI90qM2CWO3bsBIx9yul7rGoeHvC8S3rWd0NXfSZryyiEflxquwpAFjAMTCMMT0VlHGFAQ00t1t%2BIf8H8DtF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLm0fR%2FwCwNFtrJZbx%2FsSLB9okzNNBuMJ8mJvJG%2BE%2FxPxtx%2FDt%2Fd%2Ba2rapo3gLTPEFtqGqzX08UWmJ5alxaRs8RC28LJtcsiAFt33gAOfunW39ah0PRF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLrWXh%2FwpqCzNFoWkEQ3SwXfkadG%2F2edTEDCmYBvjJLbpDyuScgfc5DwZNqNhr2j2cGneNILGSD7PcPq1n5oszlCqQybPliYpsbhRja3ykArm6No954e8Ka9c6dd3EF3b6r%2FZ6ObkuLcieAYQbF3K3R2%2BXIRRt%2Fuu2tv63sHS%2Fn%2BjZ38nh7w9FqdvZTeELUfaGDTT2%2BkxyRW0i%2BTiJWMA3RvubMh5Hz8rg7La%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5fLm0k8GatosCX%2BrzvbWl00iuWm2kLbN5MX7sAwcAZCgKNxypX5eV03VdbiOl65Yad41m1BYAQq2A%2Fs8RkxnyYogDtiZFxuBBGxTg5%2BVLV2%2Frd%2F5A9D1JfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHy61x4b8P281rHL4RtG%2B0XUcUzWulxyLavtjbaCYRugPzBpTyCxHH%2FLOlPqSeF%2FFTy6g0tpYS2CeSsUZdLKSLyjLBBmPHkumzcygAbGPylflz7WPUNNsvBzyy3cM0%2BrKswAYG3jljDi1iGzBgwEzg4Up%2Fs%2FIf8AA%2FO3%2BYf8H8rnTL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXwEek6tcaDrWvvrmp2LaNNeQWVvYSN5dttZMRAeXmSElRk5VVCDjAO3cLTeIr%2FQdLW%2FvtJg%2FstLiRtNg8qRN4gUQwOseRCGKsxGQOhIC4VLVL%2Bul%2FwBBtWevn%2BDt%2Bp0a%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5dSTw94ei1O3spvCFqPtDBpp7fSY5IraRfJxErGAbo33NmQ8j5%2BVwdmd4Fsr%2FAEnWtY0u9vZriPTDaW0EykzSWyMIiIEHl4MZAAdwE4QMQOqXNReS08aeH4EkuLMR2s8RgtIcxw8W37qP92N0WQMvjjLcpt%2BRt2%2FryuJa%2FwBeZoL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FAHsYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl4mp23hfTNZs9Jk8GxXN7dsskqWGkxSi12%2BTkKWhUPCdzBpOoJIGD9zlLGw1XTvAuleME1%2FUzc6dHHCkJYrAkTSRAQrHs%2FeKVI3PuwCijBI%2BXoDo0Y%2BL9i%2FwBt1Wy8jTY3NpZO%2FkRkPEohjHljdb%2FMNxAA4JJXaQHZ8yXm%2FwAFcL6P%2Butjpl8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLF8IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfL43TtK1HxDpsniga7qGlT2bzWtpBY7ltrNUkRY4hH5eJYjtBd8hQFAI%2BU7ZjNP4huvB6w32oaTFeWEiSrYQmNoFKW2I4CqcR7tpLfMF%2BYEgLhUtf69f8gejOsXwh4eOfO8N6ZH%2B9jE3labG%2FlSHysRx5g%2FeRHLbpDyuW5XB8sXwh4eOfO8N6ZH%2B9jE3labG%2FlSHysRx5g%2FeRHLbpDyuW5XB8vjLPw9qV7qOsWT61qenWeirDa2v9n3LvLC7QwgJu8vc0OQC2Ng%2BXcw7pHZxasNL8KeLk1i7SdZLazktkTyrVIZWiHlRxbMFSpBZw2AyAAZHyC1%2FD8dhf8H8Dt18IeHjnzvDemR%2FvYxN5Wmxv5Uh8rEceYP3kRy26Q8rluVwfLrXPh%2FwpZNAuoaFpFqbm6igO3To22TkRkQxZg%2FeRsN%2BZDgjJGQfucd4jGo3%2FAIimh0yHxJLJp0K2sUOhSrZ2liT5IaATFMuM%2FMThcBV%2BXaCUoS2k3iPwl4Dvbm9vYZE1FbDzLfEBtw21VEQWPDDEYO8EhWyOeiC1Sfp%2BJXf5%2Fgeg2%2FhnQJrm4huPCNlbCKWESyLpkTqHPlfJD%2B5%2FeRElw0jYK5PQcpYXwh4eOfO8N6ZH%2B9jE3labG%2FlSHysRx5g%2FeRHLbpDyuW5XB8vk7y81fTpdVsrGWGymS8sdLt7gP5v9nrKkAZIVZAChwc%2Fd5VTjP3bFnpF14J8ReHLeDV9TuLe6cadPBdN9oa3IRJALdmiH7k7QrlQBgDoVygrP%2BvJP9RPQ6RfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHyxfCHh4587w3pkf72MTeVpsb%2BVIfKxHHmD95EctukPK5blcHy%2BAj0nVrjQda199c1OxbRpryCyt7CRvLttrJiIDy8yQkqMnKqoQcYB299pNr%2FaFr4f1bzbu1%2BzQRr5dpEFSPzEt%2F3KIIvngOMls%2FIQeRt%2Fdi1V%2FT8Qejt6%2FgKvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP8AexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FAHsYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgGSvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5YvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5YvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP8AexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgGSvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5YvhDw8c%2Bd4b0yP97GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FAHsYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2FwB7GJvK02N%2FKkPlYjjzB%2B8iOW3SHlctyuD5etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YBkr4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BWL4Q8PHPneG9Mj%2FexibytNjfypD5WI48wfvIjlt0h5XLcrg%2BXrQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZK%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pli%2BEPDxz53hvTI%2F3sYm8rTY38qQ%2BViOPMH7yI5bdIeVy3K4Pl60EHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgHzF8ULOKw%2BImp20Nla2SIsBNvagCKNjBGWC4VcjJPOBnrgUVJ8VovI%2BI%2BpQ%2FZ4bby4rZfIgOY48W8Y2qcD5R0HA4HQUUAfQfhAZ8I%2BH5szfu7C0j88QZki3R258qMeUd0T4y75O0g8jb%2B7xF%2BGdjFqD3dvqviHStzss0OmXbJHBLKYjshUQjdFyMvwB5YyPlO3b8IDPhHw%2FNmb93YWkfniDMkW6O3PlRjyjuifGXfJ2kHkbf3etBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sC%2Bljn7DwTZ2mgR6Rdz6ncRQvErTTStPLbPugZYYG8kZgyq7mAAGznGDs0%2F7GQ6rp1%2B32i1bTlFusNqmY4C4gHlRr5PzwkA5k425bpj93dgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sA5a%2B%2BHemXurHUkm1TR52iS0uho8rRKuVhVYkAhHmRdy%2FAGOeBhNOPwrp8UejRi3mtY9HuEeJbdS5gkZYx5SM0O6SFizM8hIII5IwdmtBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2Fdi02DcSK2EaRKYPswhCW%2F8Ao8O77LnyP3EH7kboGx8z8bcdtv7vGTwhp7%2BGIdAvobiS1gWOBpNu%2BWBi0DeXE4hXfEzDLScYx2x%2B72oIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sA53w94ItdAubW5e81i5ms0jt0e5uHuBZsTF%2B7gUwhWiZTtaQAbQvG0hirY%2FAOkxzXTeXd20NxJF51vbktFazb4XC26%2BTzGxC73GANgyBtOzpIIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7svrcCi2ixvqen3zie2%2Fs9Pswgto8xQ7xAPJjXyfnhIBy%2FG3LdMfu%2BeHwy0k31tNLPrMVnbOqvpsd1JLbROzxP5UaNFl4S2CzZAGznGDs6%2BCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuxaAZOseFdM1%2B0s7TVbJkgspowqWyH%2FRmKxKIIcRDfAwJ3NxjHOAMJYudCt7y40ma4hktzpNxG0S2sWRbOUiUQRfuRvgOSWfjaV7BcJegg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sAx7XwpZWuiXelLHPbQ3LSRzvBGGe1M5iLQwHyAGgOcF8fLt5xtOzB8T6WLKx0i2fSPEk66fGsEd7oMn%2BkWTCKMGKP92nmRMBkv%2FeyOPujtoIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7Vh3OE%2BF3h%2BTSIL2%2BbSb3SoppYYo1uUMl3HgQ5XmLmORidzDaFC9sZTrW0SOTUtPvXNxaHT0%2BzCG0TMcG8QDyox5HzxEA5k425bpj93egg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2Fu29f6%2BRKVjEHhCyfwtF4fuxdfZoVjt2mRd81uxaBhHE3kjfEWGWfHGOcY%2BS5BoccGvQasDc20lvbR2BhtkzFbgtAwiiXyBviPIMmRtBb7uP3d%2BCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuzrcfkchN8MdFn1N7lm1SwtZGCXmnafO62wkfyd0aIIgXibA3uCoGwdMHZ0K6JGupaZek3NqdNQWyw2y7o4N4gHlRgw5kiIBzJkbct0x%2B7vQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AZ2n%2BHbPTbq7uYbZ7SW5aKO4NvHv%2BzttgUQwfueYWUAM%2FAXb2IJSCDwrZpo2maZdLctFprwKsoG%2BSF1MDLHGwhHmQsw3O%2FGCvOACE2IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7s%2F4H4bB%2FX3nJ3Pw20q61d755dWsIZAsF3Y6dO6W4ZlhUxoqwgvCwA3uCANnOMHZYXwFpv8AwjlposzahFHYzhorqBybiyldo2CQSCEF4sscyHpt5%2B6dnSQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392dLAYLeB9Hms7u1u7JxHdCCC6MaFjAyiALHAfJGYiFXc4xt2%2Fw4OyLw94HtNAu7W6a71e5uLRI7ZXubh7j7ISY%2FwB3AphCtEwYq0gA2heNp3Fejgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuzrcOljHtfClla6Jd6Usc9tDctJHO8EYZ7UzmItDAfIAaA5wXx8u3nG07J7XQvsr6O32i%2Bg%2FslFtsQ%2FMF3LAvkj9wPNhOMs%2FG0gnjH7vRgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sB6hBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgHzN8VovI%2BI%2BpQ%2FZ4bby4rZfIgOY48W8Y2qcD5R0HA4HQUUfFaLyPiPqUP2eG28uK2XyIDmOPFvGNqnA%2BUdBwOB0FFAH0H4QGfCPh%2BbM37uwtI%2FPEGZIt0dufKjHlHdE%2BMu%2BTtIPI2%2Fu9aCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O393k%2BEBnwj4fmzN%2B7sLSPzxBmSLdHbnyox5R3RPjLvk7SDyNv7vWgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YB8zfFaLyPiPqUP2eG28uK2XyIDmOPFvGNqnA%2BUdBwOB0FFHxWi8j4j6lD9nhtvLitl8iA5jjxbxjapwPlHQcDgdBRQB9B%2BEBnwj4fmzN%2B7sLSPzxBmSLdHbnyox5R3RPjLvk7SDyNv7vya1t%2FhvHqusW3i2OGzvU1ObK2z3BEKK6bYkCR7DGcSAk7WAxgDIK%2Bs%2BEBnwj4fmzN%2B7sLSPzxBmSLdHbnyox5R3RPjLvk7SDyNv7vkdI%2F4S7wtLqkNp4CMy%2F2ozQz2t5CgjjkaI%2BVGGjJMR2oCwAwAc7Cnyrr8v8AIr7PzX5MvaTqXh7w34GOveGrRn09bhfMMTOXid3gWSKEzRbnjbaSxOCSMDBxsc%2Fi%2FV9OextH8F3Nvqk0jQWNlbzREwxoLc%2BWj%2BVtWFh945O3aRkEDY%2B%2Bg1zW%2FDM0M%2FhT%2BzJ7a8t7eC3EqSmGISWx2xFIwPKIBLHcdpT0GE159Lux4q0O7jimt7Swja3mW2iBjtmcW4WKL92C8RwQXC%2FKC3Kbflr1%2FrQj%2BvxMu78U6pbTm30Lwhc302nCGG4%2BzSwolgWEWbWE%2BWd6fKN5A4znKgLtcfGUMehaJqel6RLIbqdbGO3jVYpLN9iE20W6IBoi0W1myMHoRtASo1r4m8J6hfvonheC%2FhuLiJkNrIsTWTssIeFS8f7yA7YxuQAAKclSuVW18H3%2BlWnhmEQrNLYaybi9mt4dotvNAJjhUxjdCSy7mBO3HbadiWqXy%2F4PyG9L%2FP8ALQ6TR59QeSAXmgS6UsKJGGhMcv2Ml4gLaMLF80TKqszjIX5huGz5OZ%2BI%2BijU9L0HTDbpb7tShtAYkwLMtCuIoD5S74sgEt2K47YTsIPPg1CKA6a1tb28UUYubZFZbZiYQbWFfKBaEgAtJjAweV2%2FJka%2FpF1cT%2BG3ttPULpuqW5mEMfFkmyMGOD90u%2BHJBZh0x2Cny1vb1%2FUadr%2Bj%2FIypdSk1H4e2a2am3vrsJpCssSo9pIxiSSKEeXgxYR2Yg8FcA8fJj%2BDha2vhPwelzZy3Eia1Lbw3GSr2j7ycR%2Fuv3kbBTuJPBJ5BUbN3S%2FC93a%2BMfNlsUs9I0%2BXzrQ2kW%2Fy7icQh4owY%2BYRhwXCgAOfulDsoaP4X1ex0jwtDPp7pNpmtPJcFVVmtY3bISLCfPE25SzAnac5xtPl0nfXu1%2FX5iaSVu1%2Fyf%2FALGjeNb3ULpnsPCVydLsbpbE3ljLDI9oB5QeKKHyw5hJVcnrtJPylQFs6v4qvNK1yPRNF8Ntf6naQwGSK3nhhFnG5iHkwbotzxEoNzBRtBzlcDZyl94N1mfUrgJ4LtrDUkuoo4db0q7aGC1zs2mOBUDOozhnIPJf5lC%2FLr%2BMfDd9evDHN4LttbtYfs0UYspvsklmwCBoVfYPNgO77wHy7pMlNo2r7KD7TNi5vbS4j8JXNxodzau1%2FDDDE8Zhk0xzGh8qNfKHmREKQx6DPBG0bM1vHOp2tnd3ln4LuWtdHuGtZ57WeHZaRI0YeOAGIM8ZEYLfKMeq4BWa18MaxZaf4TgnWS5k0rVFM0oG57OFgAsMZKZkiwyBnBOCp7L8j7Hw7qNt4J1%2FTm00Wt3LNeRQLboGMQmaMpFEfLwYX43Pxtxzt2nyx3V%2Fn%2Bn%2FBGknb5fr%2FwCzqXimXTho8GiaBNqGo3MKNDbWoWMWcOLcmNHaHHkNkBn7EY%2BXb%2B7s%2BFtdm1a9vbabQ5dGbSpIbbYNkklvu8r9zGqRY8htnLZ4GGBAwUw7i21rw%2Fd6Dd6XCt5qttYQ2F1pJlSKUJ%2B4OICUIaINkO%2FIG5vmXb8k%2FgQXr%2BJfEVzfadb6dJHPbW4WxAla1XEQW3XCEFdoUSEEBdoIwPmVq138%2Fzt%2BRF3ZX8vyIfGWg6drXijwhpGq28q2YeVHtbaNhHCRHARFEyxqWiz1fHGW5XbhIp%2FB9r4H1fS9c8PRy6cxvobTUoBO8iMsphBijMifOmcnfkHOR14TR8VWevWmreHNT0TRZbw6XI0MtnbOkSW%2B9IFEUTNGN0XXLhTj5uU2%2FJHb6fr%2FiPVLH%2B2NBXQNJ0i8hKQIVuJHx5WyKIxxgLBuCM55wR1AT5FHpb5%2Ff%2FAJFPb5E%2FiLxLqfhlfMtfCrtb2PkQvdfaYLaC1D%2BUDBAzxgvCSqhmwMc8rtG3G1nxVeXOheEtX8N6TPsnv4oREkiQCEbU%2FwBDjbYN0LlMluVymDjAC19S8L6tDr2oSr4Is9Skllggt7x591vZIViAhELx%2FPEp4LoowpbBQg7Zk8M%2BIdO8EaBGukG71TQ9VWRoNyq2DIuI4X2YMTBg7MWO0gg%2Fdwijsm%2B6%2FwCD939XG92vX8tP6%2FI2tf8AE%2BqeG4lltvCchgshBE9y1zBbQ2gfygbeFnj%2BeElVDNgY55XaNu34Z1S113Q9P1eytpLW3ZUiRUgBa05hBgixFhoSVO588Y6jH7vgr%2Fwzq8et3048C2uoTTSW8NvdSzh4LBCsQEIhZCHiQ8F0UYUtgqQdvX%2BBNIv9E8L2VlqUMkN3ZytA8iRh3i3SxkJFiM7oZBgu2fl55G3924%2FDd%2F1%2FX9XE99P6%2Fr%2BrHQQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2FwBn8uD%2FAEeHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgBBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P8AZ%2FLg%2FwBHh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3ZBB5Hk%2FuPs%2F2fy4P9Hh3fZc%2BR%2B4h%2FcjdA2Pmfjbj%2BHb%2B7IIPI8n9x9n%2Bz%2BXB%2Fo8O77LnyP3EP7kboGx8z8bcfw7f3YAQQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FAGfy4P8AR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392QQeR5P7j7P9n8uD%2FR4d32XPkfuIf3I3QNj5n424%2Fh2%2FuyCDyPJ%2FcfZ%2Fs%2Flwf6PDu%2By58j9xD%2B5G6BsfM%2FG3H8O392AEEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdkEHkeT%2B4%2Bz%2FZ%2FLg%2F0eHd9lz5H7iH9yN0DY%2BZ%2BNuP4dv7sgg8jyf3H2f7P5cH%2Bjw7vsufI%2FcQ%2FuRugbHzPxtx%2FDt%2FdgHzN8VovI%2BI%2BpQ%2FZ4bby4rZfIgOY48W8Y2qcD5R0HA4HQUUfFaLyPiPqUP2eG28uK2XyIDmOPFvGNqnA%2BUdBwOB0FFAHUaP8bRpWkafZnQXlmsoIreO4%2B1xhlRFjDIuYSQjmIFgSTzwRhcW0%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAGRrnxR0DxHZQ2epeChJBbyI1ssd%2Bsf2dFCgxIVhBCELyDn7xwRhdtrSPjFpeg2q22leD%2FskaPuiKXyFo1JQugZoSxV%2FLG4sS3PBGF2lFC0Dcup8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQAJ8eIYdnkeFvJ8ralv5d3GPIiGzMKfuOEbyxkdeeCMLtE%2BPEMOzyPC3k%2BVtS38u7jHkRDZmFP3HCN5YyOvPBGF2lFAAnx4hh2eR4W8nytqW%2Fl3cY8iIbMwp%2B44RvLGR154Iwu0T48Qw7PI8LeT5W1Lfy7uMeRENmYU%2FccI3ljI688EYXaUUACfHiGHZ5HhbyfK2pb%2BXdxjyIhszCn7jhG8sZHXngjC7RPjxDDs8jwt5PlbUt%2FLu4x5EQ2ZhT9xwjeWMjrzwRhdpRQB5n4r1yLxJ4judUt9PTT4ZViSO1jYMsSpGqAAgAYwvTAx0ooooA%2F%2FZ'

urldecoded = urllib.parse.unquote(data)
base64decoded = base64.b64decode(urldecoded)
print(base64decoded[:10])
```

Output:

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF'
```

Next, you want to write this JPEG data to a file.

```py
import pathlib

jpeg_path = pathlib.Path('test.jpg')
jpeg_path.write_bytes(base64decoded)
```

Finally, you will use pytesseract to perform the OCR.

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg')))
```

**NOTE: I ran the image through the tesseract OCR in CyberChef and it failed. You may need to do this with a better image.**

Note: the tool that I started with to help me figure this out is [CyberChef](https://github.com/gchq/CyberChef).

Here is a CyberChef recipe that you can plug your data into and determine that the result is indeed JPEG.

```json
[
  { "op": "URL Decode",
    "args": [] },
  { "op": "From Base64",
    "args": ["A-Za-z0-9+/=", true, false] },
  { "op": "Detect File Type",
    "args": [true, true, true, true, true, true, true] }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Have successfully gotten the magic JFIF string, but now I am completely lost. I have no idea how to have pytesseract (and maybe PIL/pillow in tandem) convert to text... Do I need to first convert and save the string as a JPEG? Then run image to text? Please help a noob! x

Comment: The bytes output found in the variable `base64decoded` is a JPEG. I think what you're asking is: "do you need to write those bytes to a file?" If you're using pytesseract, it looks like the data needs to be in a file. https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ I have adjusted the answer to show you how to write to a file.